# SDL Tridion Content Porter (2009 SP2) Access Issue

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

I wanted to know if there's a way out to provide Content Porter rights to a user without setting his 'System Administrator' property. Currently, a user is only able to use Content Porter successfully only if the check-box for this property is selected. But the problem with this is that once the user is system Administrator, he gets access to all the CMS publications which is not desired. User's access to any publications is being managed via groups.

Wish to know if there's a way by which user can see only specific publications and use Content Porter to export/import items belonging to only those publications.

Comment: Hi Anonymous, if you found Nuno's answer helpful maybe you should consider joining the site!

Comment: What error do the user's get? Publication access through groups helps, but be sure users have scope (set in group membership), permissions (set on organizational items), and rights (set in publications) for either the export or import.

Answer (score 5):

The Tridion security model is enforced on the back-end, not per application, so what you're asking for (allowing a user to have a different security access based on the application he uses) is not possible (and this is a *good thing*).

If the user must export an item, then the user must be able to read it. If a user must import an item, then the user must be able to write it. Simple really.

Your assertion that "a user is only able to use Content Porter successfully only if the check-box for this property is selected" is incorrect. You can use Content Porter successfully if you have permissions to execute the actions you need to.

Comment: Thnx for the response, but I'm not sure if I follow you.
To be precise, "so what you're asking for.. is not possible" and "Your assertion.. is incorrect" seem to contradict.
Say I've 10 CMS publications in total, I only check 3 in a grp & give access to a user to that grp. So he can only work with those 3 publications. But he's not able to use CP for them. I make the user System Admin & now he's able to use CP. However now he has access to all the 10 publications!
Req- User has access to work with 3 publications only & use CP successfully. Possible? Basic min permissions for a user to run CP?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Content Porter uses the same permissions as the CM, so if you can read something you can export it. If this is not the case for you, I'd recommend getting in touch with Customer Support because that sounds like a bug.